# Restrict URL by IP range in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I just wondering if there's a way to restrict a URL path by certain IP range using .htaccess.

Please note that yes this is possible in vhost config, I just wanna know if anyone have tried it in htaccess..

Comment: Just FYI, IP addresses can be "faked" with the help of anonizers, proxies, or tor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working.

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^127\.0\.0\.
 RewriteRule ^(user|admin) - [F]
```

Comment: This answer worked fine for me on local dev, but when I moved to my live server it no longer worked (yes I did change ip!) moved to solution with FilesMatch instead

Comment: @autopoietic is the %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} set on your live server?

Comment: I used this solution but changed the condition to `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^10\.` to allow access only to local LAN

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin/
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried this RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^255\.10
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule (.*) - [F] .. But its not working,,... did I missed out anything? tnx

Comment: I edited my code. Try it now and don't forget to replace the ip range with yours.

Comment: Hi thanks.. I used the code above as my reference. somehow this part wasn't working for me. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin/